# How to subtract dates in postgres sql with inclusiveness in both dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to subtract two dates in postgres sql. example 2022-10-31 and 2022-11-1. So I did below approach.

```
select (date_column1 - date_column_2) as date_diff
from table;
```

My expected output is 2 days (data type of column is interval). But I'm only seeing 1 day as output.

Comment: Why do you expect a difference of 2 days, when in fact it's just one day? There is no October 32nd nor November 0

Comment: When you do this, you will only miss 1 second: `select '2023-03-13 23:59:59'::timestamp - '2023-03-12 00:00:00'::timestamp;`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is 1 day, so if you need 2 as answer simply add 1 to the result

```
select ('2023-11-01':: Date - '2023-10-31' ::date) +1 as date_diff
;
```

| date_diff |
| --- |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dIYx_xsa)

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference between 42 and 43?. It's `one` .

But, of course, 42 and 43 are `two` adjacent numbers.

It's the old question of the fence posts and the distance between them: If the fence consists of two posts and the distance between two posts is one meter, the fence is one meter long.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively doing:

```
select '11/01/2022 00:00:00'::timestamptz - '10/31/2022 00:00:00'::timestamptz;
 ?column? 
----------
 1 day
```

In other words Midnight to Midnight which is generally a 24 hour period, with exceptions below.

You can see that best across a Day light savings time change. For here(USA) that occurred on March 12, 2023 and November 5, 2023 so:

```
--Day before change

select '03/12/2023 00:00:00'::timestamptz - '03/11/2023 00:00:00'::timestamptz;
 ?column? 
----------
 1 day

--Day of change to DST

select '03/13/2023 00:00:00'::timestamptz - '03/12/2023 00:00:00'::timestamptz;
 ?column? 
----------
 23:00:00

--Day of change back to standard time

select '11/06/2023 00:00:00'::timestamptz - '11/05/2023 00:00:00'::timestamptz;
    ?column?    
----------------
 1 day 01:00:00
```